# Syncronize folder on USB drive for Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, usb-drive

I have a folder on an external USB drive that I'd like to synchronize in Ubuntu One but when I right click on the folder, or any other folder on the USB drive for that matter, I don't get the option to sync with Ubuntu One. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

From the Ubuntu One [FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/CanISyncAFolderOutsideMyHomeFolder):

> ### Can I synchronize a folder outside my home folder?
>
> No, currently you can only select to synchronize folders inside your home directory.

Since your usb drive is mounted outside of your home folder (usually `/media`) you **can not** currently synchronize it using Ubuntu One.